# PHP str_replace in while loop. How i removed \\/ from script output

Tags: php

In this script, the URL is displayed in wrong just like `https:\\/\\/www.site.com\\/mypage`. how I remove `\` in this URL? Thank you

```php
$q="select * from post order by id";
$qr=$conn->query($q) or die($q);
$post_list=array();
$i=0;
while($r=$qr->fetch_object())
{
  $post_list[$i]["id"]=$r->id;
  $post_list[$i]["title"]=$r->title;
  $post_list[$i]["image"]=$r->image;
  $post_list[$i]["url"]=$r->url;
  $i++;
}
$response['post_list'] = $post_list;
```

Comment: My guess is that the the `\\` characters have been added by some ill-conceived attempt at sanitisation before the data was added to the database. You might do better to address that first.

Comment: Use [`stripslashes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Comment: Nothing in this code adds or removes slashes. What does the original data on DB look like, as seen by your favourite GUI client (MySQL Workbench, DBeaver, whatever)?